# String array to XML

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a string array in c# that contains lines of an address. There is a minimum of 2 and a maximum of 4 lines in the array. This array needs to be turned into an XML query that requires 4 address elements. This is how I am doing it and it works but seems like there should be a more efficient way.

```
        switch (address.Length)
        {
            case 2:
                address2[0] = "";
                address2[1] = "";
                address2[2] = address[0];
                address2[3] = address[1];
                break;
            case 3:
                address2[0] = "";
                address2[1] = address[0];
                address2[2] = address[1];
                address2[3] = address[2];
                break;
            case 4:
                address2[0] = address[0];
                address2[1] = address[1];
                address2[2] = address[2];
                address2[3] = address[3];
                break;
            default:
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Address Block Length");
                break;
        }
```

This populates a second string array that eventually creates XML like:

```
            "<ADDRESS0>" + address2[0] + "</ADDRESS0>" +
            "<ADDRESS1>" + address2[1] + "</ADDRESS1>" +
            "<ADDRESS2>" + address2[2] + "</ADDRESS2>" +
            "<ADDRESS3>" + address2[3] + "</ADDRESS3>"
```

The XML must contain the 4 address elements even if the inner text is empty.

Comment: There's a whole set of functionality called [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) which lets you "query" your xml.  It also can help build XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *really* not a good idea to create XML via string concatenation.  You *will* mess up at some point.

You could use LINQ to XML to create your elements, padding the array with *n* extra blank lines at the front to get you 4 in total:

```
string[] address = {"first", "second", "third"};

var extra = Math.Max(0, 4 - address.Length);

var elements = Enumerable.Repeat("", extra)
    .Concat(address)
    .Select((line, index) => new XElement("ADDRESS" + index, line));
```

Output:

```
<ADDRESS0></ADDRESS0>
<ADDRESS1>first</ADDRESS1>
<ADDRESS2>second</ADDRESS2>
<ADDRESS3>third</ADDRESS3>
```

See a working demo here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sRffH5

Answer (score 1):

I think that's probably the most efficient thing you can do in actually generating the values - however, you can also do it in a loop:

```
var address = new string[]{ "a", "b", "c" };
var address2 = new string[]{ "", "", "", "" };

for (int i = 0; i < address.Length; i++)
{
    address2[address2.Length - i - 1] = address[address.Length - i - 1];
}
```